# Qgis: Export only some columns of the selected objects to CSV

Tags: qgis, export, csv

I have a layer with a table containing several columns. 
If I right click on the layer --> Save as.. --> CSV and chose to only include my selection I get a nice CSV file with all columns for the selected objects.

However, I only want the data from one specific column to be exported to the CSV file.

How would I go around this?

Answer (score 4):

After you selected your features, from the toolbar go to *Layer > Save As...*. Check the **Save only selected features** option and save it as a new shapefile (also add it to the map canvas for convenience by checking the *Add saved file to map* option).

Then from the toolbar, go to *MMQGIS > Import/Export > Attributes Export to CSV File*, select your layer and the column(s) you want exported.

**Note, you may need to enable the MMQGIS plugin from *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...***.

Hope this helps!